# How can i make a remote tab local with jquery ui tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a local main tab and a tab loading via ajax. The issue is that the user needs to go to a third tab and come back to the ajax tab with the content still there. Right now it just reloads the ajax tab each time you click on it and the user loses their info. I am trying to load the tab via ajax and then turn it into a local tab so the user doesn't lose their information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to modify the jQuery tabs script in order to do this. You'll need to identify the tab you don't want loaded a second time and skip of the Ajax call on this condition. You can add a class name to this tab when it is clicked, and then skip the Ajax call if the tab has this class name.